# How do I completely disable cache for a vue.js static app in nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I'm using the following headers, but even with chrome devtools open and cache disabled, the content is still cached in the browser.

It is a compiled vue.js 2.x app.

Here are the nginx headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sun, 20 Jan 2019 00:47:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 3162
Connection: keep-alive
Expires: Sun, 20 Jan 2019 00:47:24 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

What am I doing wrong? The only way I can clear cache is to do it at the browser level which is annoying.

We do continuous deployment and caching is not desired.

It is the index.html page that loads all the assets which are hashed, but that index.html page is being cached in Chrome/Linux and Mac.

Comment: The only obvious problem I see is that you have two Cache-Control headers. I'm not sure what exactly a browser is supposed to do when that happens, but it probably won't be what you want.

Comment: BTW, the Pragma header is not needed unless you expect to serve web browsers from the 1990s. It's been deprecated for some 20 years now.

Comment: I'm not sure why I get two headers. This is my nginx config: `add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';`

Comment: Is your app sending its own Cache-Control header, then?

Comment: no this is an index.html page served by nginx statically.

Comment: Maybe the `Cache-Control` is included in some other nginx config file.